# Why doesn't this loop print?

Tags: java

I am trying to print numbers that are divisible by 5, that goes all the way up to 500.
However, nothing gets printed out in my current program.

**Code:**

```
public class Messin {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (int prime = 5; prime == 500; prime++ ) {
            if (prime % 5 != 0 )
                System.out.print(prime);
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your for loop to:

```
for (int prime = 5; prime <= 500; prime++ ) {
    // ...
}
```

The problem with your original for loop is that, the initial value doesn't satisfy the loop condition (prime == 500), and hence it doesn't run at all.

And to find numbers divisible by 5, it should be:

```
if (prime % 5 == 0)
```

A number with remainder 0 when divided by 5, is well.. divisible by 5.

Answer (score 1):

```
prime == 500 // false as prime contain 5 not 500
```

is wrong, because you declare `int prime = 5`. So loops does not iterate for a single time!

Try this:

```
for (int prime = 5; prime <= 500; prime++ ) {
....
```

Moreover,

> I'm trying to print numbers that are divisible by 5

So change

```
if (prime % 5 !=0 )
```

to

```
if (prime % 5 == 0)
```

because if `prime` is divisible by `5` then the remainder will be `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `prime==500` to be `prime <= 500`

Comment: Thanks guys very helpful